# How to show lat long location on the street

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have an application where one user can share his travel-trips in realtime with others and they can see the path taken by him in real time. I do it by getting the location data(latitude, longitude) and plot it in the map view using polyline to construct the path. But this lat long location sometimes goes out side the street and looks as if user is driving through the buildings. Is there a way I can correct(latitude-longitude) location to always be on the street?
[image]

Comment: if you share some screenshots, you will get better help

Comment: I believe I need some sort of map matching.